# Static method on a class with a private constructor that internally creates itself

Tags: java, design-patterns, concurrency

This is more of a "is this safe, stupid, or completely unnecessary" question.  I'm trying to figure out if this code pattern is reasonable:

```
public class SomeClass {

    private String someField;
    // Other fields here omitted for clarity

    private SomeClass() {
        someField = "some initialization goes here";
        // More initialization of omitted fields
    }

    public static void doSomething(MyObject myObject) {

        SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();

        // Do things with myObject and someClass instance

    }
}
```

Is there an obvious (or non-obvious) problem with this code?  I think the general goal was to separate the complexity of activity in the `doSomething` method from elsewhere in the code, but still leave the `SomeClass` class open for flexibility.  Maybe?

Would there be concurrency/synchronization problems with something like this?

I apologize for the very ambiguous example code.

Comment: @AmitD How so? OP is using a new instance with every call to the static method; there is no threat to concurrency/synchronization.

Comment: @Vulcan My bad I didn't notice the initialization inside static method.

Comment: I would make the field final if possible, otherwise I don't see a problem with it.

Comment: In the end, this is used like a private/local class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There would not be any concurrency or synchronization problems with this concept, because for every call to the static method, there is an individual instance of `SomeClass`, meaning that no values will ever be accessed by multiple threads simultaneously.

As for the feasibility of this design pattern, I'd say it's a reasonable pattern.  I can't think of any Java API classes which implement such a pattern, but I'll add any to this answer if I find some.  Normally, you'll see classes with private constructors to not use the object and instead provide a bank of static methods, but there's not really any reason not to do what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using it is a `mix-up` of `static factories` and normal `object creation`. So in your case, you won't have any `concurrency issue`.

But still, assuming that you wanted to know about `static factory`, using static factory is preferable, in case you just want a single instance of your class to roam around, or you can also use them to return an instance of any subtype.

It is the very first item in the book: - `Effective Java` that says, `Consider static factory methods instead of constructors`.

Here is a quote from the advantages listed in that item: -

> One advantage of static factory methods is that, they have names,
>   unlike constructors. If parameters to a constructor do not, in and of
>   themselves, describe the object being returned, a static factory with
>   a well-chosen name is easier to use.

So, you can have different kinds of `static methods` with thier name showing what they will do. For E.G: -

- `getInstance()` should generally be used to return the existing instance
- `newInstance()` should be used to create new instance on every call

So, your `singleton` implementation should be like: -

```
public class Demo {
    private static Demo demo = new Demo();

    private Demo() {
    }

    public static Demo getInstance() {
        return demo != null? demo: new Demo();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think I was necessarily going for a `Singleton`.  So, in the absence of a need for `Singleton`, would moving the instance fields to be local to the method be preferable? Then I could eliminate instantiating `SomeClass`?

Comment: Great answer, but I'd like to point out that if `demo` is ever null (although it shouldn't be), then `getInstance()` returns a different `Demo` instance for every call.

Comment: @PattMauler. Then there would not be any problem in the way you are using. That will simply restrict other classes to create the instance using constructor. They would have to use `static method` instead.

Comment: @Vulcan. Well, once the `demo` is set, it won't be set to null, unless it is done explicitly. To save it form being set to null, from outside, we can make this class `immutable` as well.

Comment: The usage of `SomeClass` above is *not* a `Singleton`. Everytime you call `doSomething()` another object is created.

Comment: @OlafDietsche. If you read the first line of my answer, I have written that.

Comment: I disagree that the sole purpose of a static factory is for singletons. It's also great to reuse multiple cached instances, return null if necessary, or disambiguate constructors that would otherwise be confusing or have the same parameters.

Comment: @JeffBowman. Well, actually that's right. Static factory do have other purposes. I have edited my post, to reflect them.

Comment: Another key reason to use factories is if the new object needs to be registered somewhere or start a thread. You (almost) never want to leak `this` from a constructor or start a thread from a constructor, so the factory method can instantiate the object and then do whatever with it before returning.